# DB design for Global and Specific

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I need some help, inputs on DB design practices to achieve the below requirement.  The database will be PostgreSQL.

I have to design a holiday tracker with the below requirements.

1. Global Holiday for the whole country.
2. Holiday per state.

Ex :
December 25th: Holiday to the whole country. (All)
Let's Say, January 25th: Holiday for "MO, IL" states.

So when query holiday for state MO or IL it should return both December 25th and January 25th.

But when a query for other states (ex: TN) it should only return December 25th only.

Tried DB design.
[image]

With this design for find global holidays, I have use OR Condition.

Ex;

```
select * from holiday_master hm
where exists ( select 'x' from state_holiday sh 
               where sh.holiday_id = hm.id 
                 and state_id in ("MO", "IL") )
  or not exists ( select 'x' from state_holiday sh 
                  where sh.holiday_id = hm.id )
```

One option is to add an entry for **state_holiday** with state id as All and change query as below.

```
select * from holiday_master hm
    where exists ( select 'x' from state_holiday sh 
                   where sh.holiday_id = hm.id 
                     and state_id in ("MO", "IL", "All") )
```

Please provide your great inputs here.

**Note: No of States can be increased from 1 to 1000.**

Comment: or... you can have a single table `holiday (id, date, description, state)`

Answer (score 1):

I would normally steer clear of any solution that involved a deliberate cartesian join, but based on the fact that we are dealing with very low data volumes (states < 1,000 records, holidays <= 365 records), you *could* make use of Postgres' most excellent array capabilities.

```
create table holiday_master (
  id integer not null,
  holiday_date date not null,
  description text,
  national_holiday boolean not null,
  states integer[],
  constraint holiday_master_pk primary key (id)
)
```

And then a sample query that should yield all holidays for a given state would look like:

```
select
  s.state, h.holiday_date, h.description
from
  state_master s
  cross join holiday_master h
where
  s.state = 'MO' and
 (h.national_holiday or s.id = any (h.states))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Chris for the answer. this use case runs all over the application with different scenarios. so there are possibility dependant elements (here states) can grow up to 10K and master elements (here holiday) also can grow up to 10K. so I am looking for a better design for both cases. if you have idea please help on this.

Comment: I believe if you put an index on state_master.state, holiday_master.states and holiday master.national_holiday, this should run pretty zippy.  10k records per table with the filter conditions and indexes would be no problem at all.  There are other data models I could think of, but Postgres arrays are seriously a joy to work with.